# What is the best way to detect pulses between two clock domains?

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I want to transfer a pulse from a clock domain clk1 to another clock domain clk2, but we don't know which one is faster than the other!
What is the best way to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a strobe synchronizer.

A strobe synchronizer translates a rising edge on input to a level change (T-FF). This level change is transferred to the second clock domain via 2-FF synchronizer. The information is then restored by an XOR gate. (Note: A T-FF is a D-FF with a XOR to invert the state on every high input.)

In addition, a busy state can be calculated to notify the sending clock domain about the state of the overall circuit. This busy signal can be used to lock the input's rising edge detection.

**The circuit looks like this:**
[image]

**Source Code for multiple bits at once:**

```
library IEEE;
use     IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use     IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;

library PoC;
use     PoC.sync.all;


entity sync_Strobe is
    generic (
        BITS                : positive            := 1;                       -- number of bit to be synchronized
        GATED_INPUT_BY_BUSY : boolean             := TRUE;                    -- use gated input (by busy signal)
        SYNC_DEPTH          : T_MISC_SYNC_DEPTH   := T_MISC_SYNC_DEPTH'low    -- generate SYNC_DEPTH many stages, at least 2
    );
    port (
        Clock1              : in  std_logic;                            -- <Clock>  input clock domain
        Clock2              : in  std_logic;                            -- <Clock>  output clock domain
        Input               : in  std_logic_vector(BITS - 1 downto 0);  -- @Clock1:  input bits
        Output              : out std_logic_vector(BITS - 1 downto 0);  -- @Clock2:  output bits
        Busy                : out  std_logic_vector(BITS - 1 downto 0)  -- @Clock1:  busy bits
    );
end entity;


architecture rtl of sync_Strobe is
    attribute SHREG_EXTRACT : string;

    signal syncClk1_In      : std_logic_vector(BITS - 1 downto 0);
    signal syncClk1_Out     : std_logic_vector(BITS - 1 downto 0);
    signal syncClk2_In      : std_logic_vector(BITS - 1 downto 0);
    signal syncClk2_Out     : std_logic_vector(BITS - 1 downto 0);

begin
    gen : for i in 0 to BITS - 1 generate
        signal D0             : std_logic      := '0';
        signal T1             : std_logic      := '0';
        signal D2             : std_logic      := '0';

        signal Changed_Clk1   : std_logic;
        signal Changed_Clk2   : std_logic;
        signal Busy_i         : std_logic;

        -- Prevent XST from translating two FFs into SRL plus FF
        attribute SHREG_EXTRACT of D0  : signal is "NO";
        attribute SHREG_EXTRACT of T1  : signal is "NO";
        attribute SHREG_EXTRACT of D2  : signal is "NO";

    begin
        process(Clock1)
        begin
            if rising_edge(Clock1) then
                -- input delay for rising edge detection
                D0    <= Input(i);

                -- T-FF to converts a strobe to a flag signal
                if GATED_INPUT_BY_BUSY then
                    T1  <= (Changed_Clk1 and not Busy_i) xor T1;
                else
                    T1  <= Changed_Clk1 xor T1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;

        -- D-FF for level change detection (both edges)
        D2  <= syncClk2_Out(i) when rising_edge(Clock2);

        -- assign syncClk*_In signals
        syncClk2_In(i)  <= T1;
        syncClk1_In(i)  <= syncClk2_Out(i);         -- D2

        Changed_Clk1    <= not D0 and Input(i);     -- rising edge detection
        Changed_Clk2    <= syncClk2_Out(i) xor D2;  -- level change detection; restore strobe signal from flag
        Busy_i          <= T1 xor syncClk1_Out(i);  -- calculate busy signal

        -- output signals
        Output(i)        <= Changed_Clk2;
        Busy(i)          <= Busy_i;
    end generate;

    syncClk2 : entity PoC.sync_Bits
        generic map (
            BITS        => BITS,          -- number of bit to be synchronized
            SYNC_DEPTH  => SYNC_DEPTH
        )
        port map (
            Clock       => Clock2,        -- <Clock>  output clock domain
            Input       => syncClk2_In,   -- @async:  input bits
            Output      => syncClk2_Out   -- @Clock:  output bits
        );

    syncClk1 : entity PoC.sync_Bits
        generic map (
            BITS        => BITS,          -- number of bit to be synchronized
            SYNC_DEPTH  => SYNC_DEPTH
        )
        port map (
            Clock       => Clock1,        -- <Clock>  output clock domain
            Input       => syncClk1_In,   -- @async:  input bits
            Output      => syncClk1_Out   -- @Clock:  output bits
        );
end architecture;
```

The source code can be found here: [PoC.misc.sync.Strobe](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/misc/sync/sync_Strobe.vhdl?ts=2)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I try to create my own VHDL code according to my understanding and then I will compare with your solution! Cheers,

Comment: This code is open source and licensed under Apache License 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to your issue is the Flancter, best explained by Doulos:

https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/fpga/fastcounter/

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have a verilog version of this code compatible for xilinx tools,

src_pulse -> src_clk level_convertor-> 2-Stage  dest Synchronizer -> dest_pulse detector

this is the sequence steps to follow when transmitting a pulse between 2  relation unknown clock domains.

```
   module pulse_cdc(
        input         src_clk,
        input         src_pulse,
        input         dest_clk,
        output logic  dest_pulse
    );

    (* ASYNC_REG = "TRUE" *)logic [2:0] dest_sync;
                            logic       src_clk_level = '0;

    //------------------------------//
    //-- Pulse to level convertor --//
    //------------------------------//
        always_ff @(posedge src_clk)
            if(src_pulse) src_clk_level <= #10 ~src_clk_level;
            else          src_clk_level <= #10  src_clk_level;

    //----------------------------//
    //------- Synchronizer -------//
    //----------------------------//
        always_ff @(dest_clk)begin
            dest_sync[0] <= #10 src_clk_level;
            dest_sync[1] <= #10 dest_sync[0];
            dest_sync[2] <= #10 dest_sync[1];
        end

    //-------------------------//
    //--- Pulse Generator -----//
    //-------------------------//
        always_comb dest_pulse = dest_sync[1] ^ dest_sync[2];

    endmodule
```